# How to remove stroke from smallest points with geom_count?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I'm trying to use geom_count() to size points on a ggplot by their occurrence frequency, but for some reason the smallest points end up having black strokes. I've tried different shapes, stroke = 0, everything, but I can't figure this out. I'd really appreciate any help!

Reprex:

```
library(ggplot2)

frame = data.frame(X = sample(1:7,100,replace=T),
                   Y = sample(1:7,100,replace=T))

ggplot(data = frame, aes(X, Y)) +
  scale_color_grey(start = .6, end = .2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_count(aes(color = as.factor(..n..)))
```

Example:

[image: The smallest dots have strokes?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(data = frame, aes(X, Y)) +
  scale_color_grey(start = .6, end = .2) +
  geom_point(shape=21,color='transparent') +
  geom_count(aes(color = as.factor(..n..)))
```

Output:

[image]

Or only:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(data = frame, aes(X, Y)) +
  scale_color_grey(start = .6, end = .2) +
  geom_point(color='transparent') +
  geom_count(aes(color = as.factor(..n..)))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow that's way more obvious than I was expecting thank you!!

Comment: @ThatCrazyCow Always a pleasure helping :)